# Bibtex: How can I set a urldate in @online?

Tags: bibtex, urls

I have some entries in my literature that are only URL, e.g.

```
@online{cullen,
    url = {http://www.primegrid.com/download/cullen-6679881.pdf},
    urldate = {2024-19-03},
}
```

But in the document it only says the URl, not the date.
How can I set the date?

---

*Addendum*: With your help it works for online now.
But if I have a an entry of type `@article` and want a URL, too, I code

```
@article{pocklington_original,
    author = {H. C. Pocklington},
    title = {The Determination of the Prime or Composite Nature of Large Numbers by Fermat's Theorem},
    journal = {Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society},
    volume = {18},
    year = {1914 - 1916},
    pages = {29 -- 30},
    url = {},
    publisher = {Cambridge [etc.], Cambridge Philosophical Society [etc.]},
    note = {\url{https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/86583}, (besucht am 19.02.2024)},
}
```

But I get

[image]

so the `pages` field is shown at the very end.

Comment: If and how the `urldate` field is shown in your document depends on the style you use. Please show us a small example document that reproduces your bibliography setup (so that we can see which bibliography packages and style you use) and shows the output you are asking about: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Most `biblatex` styles should show the `urldate` by default.

Comment: But note that there is a typo in this particular example `urldate = {2024-19-03},` can't be right. The date needs to be given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and there is no 19th month, so you probably want `urldate = {2024-03-19},` for *19 March 2024* (the day after tomorrow).

Comment: It's bibtex, not biblatex. Sorry

Comment: Please include a short, but compilable test document in your question, so we can see if you really use bibtex as this question claims, or biblatex like in the question which you just deleted.

Comment: I don't think the `@article` entry type is appropriate for the `pocklington_original` entry. I'd go with `@incollection` or `@inproceedings`.

Comment: @Mico thank you. And what about a book where I want s URL too?

Comment: @Lereu - Please see the addendum I've posted below my initial answer. About your question, "And what about a book where I want s URL too?" Not sure what your question is. As long as it's appropriate to use the `@book` entry type for a given entry, there should be no problem in using the `note` field to provide information about items such as a URL and the last-visited date.

Answer (score 2):

BibTeX has no built-in entry type called `@online`. Hence, BibTeX will revert to the catch-all `@misc` entry type.

Now, most BibTeX bibliography styles do *not* define the `urldate` entry type -- and hence simply ignore it. The `apacite` bibliography style, which implements the APA6 formatting guidelines (which, incidentally, are no longer the current APA guidelines), is one of the few bibliography styles that does define a field called `urldate`.

If you happen to use a bibliography style that does not define a field called `urldate`, you will need to change

```
    urldate = {2024-03-18},
```

to something like

```
    note = {Retrieved 2024-03-18},
```

I would further like to recommend that you backfill at least the `title` and `year` fields for the entry at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{cullen,
    title = {{PrimeGrid’s Cullen Prime Search}},
    year  = 2009,
    url = {http://www.primegrid.com/download/cullen-6679881.pdf},
    urldate = {2024-03-18},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{cullen}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's revised query: In my view, the main problem with the entry is that it uses an incorrect entry type. You should be using the `@incollection` entry type, not the `@article` entry type. (A fail-safe rule of thumb: Use the `@article` entry type exclusively for pieces published in scholarly journals.)

Note that I've packed some additional information in the `booktitle` field.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@incollection{pocklington_original,
    author    = {Pocklington, H. C. [Henry Cabourn]},
    title     = {The Determination of the Prime or Composite Nature 
                 of Large Numbers by {Fermat's} Theorem},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 
                 Volume XVIII, Oct.\ 26, 1914 to May 22, 1916},
    year      = {1916},
    pages     = {29--30},

    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    address   = {Cambridge and London},
    note      = {\url{https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/86583}, 
                 besucht am 19.02.2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{pocklington_original}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. I tried that for an article too, but it does not work. So I editet my question, hope that is ok to do so